# Translating label and placeholder

Tags: xml, internationalization, odoo, translate

I'm trying to translate labels and placeholders but I can't do it. All other cases I can (fields, help, text). Someone can help me?

Best regards

Edit:

If I need to translate page string and field placeholder in snippet:

```
<page name='internal_notes' string="Internal Notes">
         <field name="comment" placeholder="Internal note..."/>
</page>
```

My po (for page string)

```
#. module: base
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:base.view_partner_form
msgid "Internal Notes"
msgstr "..."
```

For placeholder I think that should be the same guideline.

Comment: Do you use POedit for translations? Are those strings you want to translate added to the file `your_language_code.po`?

Comment: If I try to export the strings, the label does not appear in the file "po". I've tried manually enter but I am not able to. I went to see the other modules and tried but could not replicate.

Comment: It happened to me sometimes, and I had to add it manually to the `.po` file like you did. You should edit your question in order to show your XML view with the label and placeholder, and what you wrote in your `.po` file to add these strings.

Comment: I edited over to format the code

Comment: I noticed that no title is being translated. I started with the ODOO in a very short time, but the analysis I did, anything with arch_db is being translated.
If you see the code above, there is not translated because it is with arch_db. Everything else is translated. In this case, I was see ir_ui_view table and in fact is the html generated there, but the content is not translated. Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, below the response of the PoEdit support :

For several days now, I'm trying to translate a WordPress theme with PoEdit. I'm able to translate 95% of my theme, but some elements, like "placeholder" values in my comments form, are not detected by PoEdit.

Let me correct that: they are not translatable. There’s nothing for Poedit to detect, because the theme’s author decided to allow translating of these strings. Even if you somehow tricked Poedit into recognising them, it would be of no use: the theme wouldn’t use the translations anyway, because it doesn’t even look for them.

I use this theme with a child theme, that's why I don't want to modify directly the code in the parent theme. How can I translate these elements with PoEdit?

You’ll have to fix the PHP code, I’m afraid.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/poedit-theme-translation